# Show Hide Menus MVC jQuery

Tags: abp

Can anyone help me out discovering the correct way to show/hide menu items according to `AbpUserRoles`?

I am simply adding two menu items that should only be available to role=`admin`.

My code causes the Admin menu to show when it should not:

**Code**:

```
var adminMenu = context.Menu.GetAdministration();
adminMenu.Items.Add(new ApplicationMenuItem("Admin.Sites", "Sites", "/Sites"));
adminMenu.Items.Add(new ApplicationMenuItem("Admin.UserSites", "User Sites", "/UserSites"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so the way I ended up doing this was by getting hold of the CurrentUser as follows:

```
public class YourProjectMenuContributor : IMenuContributor
{
    private async Task ConfigureMainMenuAsync(MenuConfigurationContext context)
    {

        if (context.GetHttpContext().User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            //....configure as required...
        }
    }
}
```